# forward and inverse search for Rmarkdown (request)

Tags: r-markdown, bookdown

I used Latex for many years and recently decided to switch to Rmarkdown, especially after the development of notebooks, bookdown, etc.

However, I'm frustrated by the fact that I cannot use forward and inverse search when using Rmarkdown files. First, I thought this was an issue with my system configuration and Rstudio. However, I was informed in another forum that forward and inverse search do not work with Rmarkdown files, but only with Rnw files.

I would like to suggest the implementation of forward-inverse search when using Rmarkdown, bookdown, etc. It would make revising our documents, books, websites, a lot easier.

Comment: Yes, that is correct: you cannot do this in R Markdown; this feature is only available for Rnw files. You can file an issue to the rmarkdown repo on Github, but I guess it won't be implemented in the foreseeable future...